# Can't execute stored procedure in zend framework

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, php-5.3, execute

i got a problem with executing a stored procedure in zend framework.
Before this problem, i was using dblib and everything was perfect. Here's the code:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare( "EXEC getParam ? , ?");
$stmt->bindParam( 1, $param['serial'] );
$stmt->bindParam( 2, $renderXml );
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now, i changed my driver from dblib to sqlsrv (runinng via wamp 32 bit) and i have following problem:

> Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error' in >..\Sqlsrv.php:206>

I searched for solution, but always everything was like my first solution that was working, before i changed sql driver.

Comment: What is `$this->_db`? Clean PDO or something extending it?

Comment: it's object of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I use this method to call a sored procedure:

To call *getParam()* with two string parameters

```
$proc = "CALL getParam(:param1, :param2)";

$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($proc);
$stmt->bindParam(':param1', $param['serial'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':param2', $renderXml ,      PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I hope it's can help you. :)

Comment: By now i have error "Invalid bind-variable" but i will test it later. Anyway, thank you for help :)